# How to generate missing ".iml" file in IntelliJ?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

When I created a new project(myProject) in IntelliJ using Maven, IntelliJ did not generate "myProject.iml" file.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using maven and want to generate missing .iml file, please follow the below steps. It should generate the file.

Navigate 'File' > 'Project Structure'

Select 'Modules'

Select 'Remove Module'

Select 'Import Module' (Select the root of the project you are currently experiencing the issue
with)

Select 'Import module from existing sources'

Select your project structure -> Mine was 'Maven'

Press 'Finish'
Press 'OK'